# Disable pointer-lock notification in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mouse

I have a webapp that requires the frequent and repeated use of the [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API). Using this web-API will display a browser-specific popup-message to the user, something like:

> *site* is controlling the mouse. Press ESC to exit.

The message is only displayed once in Chrome and Edge, initially, which I can cope with. However, it is displayed every single time in Firefox, which is annoying from a usability perspective.

**Where can I disable this message in Firefox?** (53.0.2) I already looked in page permissions, but there is no setting for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the `about:config` page (accessible by writing "about:config" into the URL bar), set the following:

```
pointer-lock-api.warning.timeout
```

to `0`.

This will, in essence, hide the warning immediately, without giving it time to show up.